# Is there a ready made RMagick image editor out there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rmagick

I am about to build a basic online image editor for my web application using rails and rmagick. I did a bit of googling but couldn't find any existing solution, however I'd like to be sure before I spend a lot of time rolling my own.

Is anyone aware of a plugin/gem that provides a pre-rolled image editor with undo/redo and minimal image degradation on multiple edits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this exists: Rails Image Editor

http://github.com/heurionconsulting/rails_image_editor/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but I'm building one too. I'm using the Pixastic and Raphael libraries to generate live previews. So people can actually preview the resulting image, without having to wait for the server to process it.

Features are:

- Quick fit (make the image instantly fitting a given width, height or width and height)
- Crop
- Resize
- Rotate left and right 90º (animated)
- Flip horizontal and/or vertical
- Colorize (color picker)
- Make warmer (slider)
- Make colder (slider)
- Make greyscale (one click)
- Make sepia (one click)
- Glow (slider)
- Blur (slider)
- Sharpen (slider)
- Brightness (slider)
- Contrast (slider)

Details:

- It is provided as a Rails plugin.
- Currently it only works on Paperclip attachments.
- Integration is piece of cake (js include and a link in the view, that's it!)
- It is displayed as a lightbox-like overlay
- All requests are Ajax (so no page reloading)
- I skipped RMagick and built a dedicated ImageMagick module for serverside image processing
- The whole frontend is based on Q, a javascript toolset providing a slider, color picker, floating windows, growl-like feature, I18n for javascript, decent Cookie management and much more.
- configurable with a single YAML file
- integrated languages are US English and Dutch

Possible downsides:

- Live preview on color correction is not available on IE due to lack of HTML5 canvas support
- The Q library is not free for commercial domains (only €49 per domain or €249 for a wildcard version)

This plugin will be available for free next month in Alpha release.

Comment: Any progress regarding the editor? I am much interested in it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @wout any progress ?